# Upload a photo/image to facebook with SDK

Tags: android, facebook, image, upload

What is the latest way to send a photo / image / bitmap on the wall facebook? All methods are deprecated that I found. Best if it was from the moment you click on the button.

I know that some people use it in the method, and where to insert it?:

```
 Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
            session, bitmap, callback);
    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
```

(sorry for english :P)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) for making requests to Facebook using Java. You can upload photos like this:

```
FacebookType publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
    BinaryAttachment.with("photo.png", new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath)),
    );
```

Comment: when you create facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken); what is accessToken?? (sorry for english :P)

Comment: If you have an open facebook session, you can get the access token using `session.getAccessToken()`.

Comment: I found this AccessToken accessToken =
  new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);, but now i have error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient

Comment: com.restfb.exception.FacebookNetworkException: A network error occurred while trying to communicate with Facebook: Facebook request failed (HTTP status code null) now i have this :P

Comment: Make sure that you have been granted the correct permissions to upload photos.

Comment: exception is throwing on this: AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(appID, secretID);

Comment: Application access token and user access token are different things. I don't think you can obtain a user application token from RestFB. You have to setup the login with fb in your app as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. After login is successful, you can get the current access token from the current open session.

Answer (score 1):

First Download [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) Facebbok SDK and include it in your project as library project.

In your activity,where you want to share the image ::

```
private static Bitmap b;
private static Facebook mFacebook;
private static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String[] permissions = {"photo_upload" };
final static int AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 0;
```

In  onCreate() initialize this variables ::

```
 if (Constant.FACEBOOK_APP_ID == null)
 {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be "
                        + "specified before running this example: see FbAPIs.java");
        return;
 }

mHandler=new Handler();
mFacebook = new Facebook(Constant.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE: 
        {
        mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

onButtonClick from where you are going to share a Image ::

```
if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) 
{
    mFacebook.authorize(TabNoteActivity.this, permissions, AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE, new LoginDialogListener());
}
else
{
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     Utils.b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);//Here I am convert the JPG image into bitmap using declaring method in the Utils class 
     byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
     params.putString (Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
     params.putString ("message"," Facebook App Testing");
     params.putByteArray("picture",byteArray);
     mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params,"POST", new PhotoUploadListener(),null);
}


    public class PhotoUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener
    {
        //@Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) 
        {

           mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
           {
            // @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"Image has been shared Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          });
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: I have a few questions:
Which class should Handler ()
                 - Android.os?
                 - Java.util.logging?
I still highlights:
SessionStore, LoginDialogListener, mAsyncRunner.request ("me / photos", params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener (), null) <- here only request, BaseRequestListener

Comment: you should import android.os. And what highlights SessionStore,LoginDialogListener?post some relevent error and code in which you are implementing this thing :)